# Did BLM post the quote “Loving your culture and placing your race first doesn't make you racist”?

Tags: politics, quotes, black-lives-matter

This image:

[image: Black woman next to the phrase below, in a post by Black Lives Matter]

indicates that BLM posted an image with the following caption:

> Loving your culture and placing your race first doesn't make you racist

Did that happen or is it fake?

Comment: I only saw that title and though this was about the Bureau of Land Management https://www.blm.gov/

Comment: Where does it attribute this quote to anyone?

Comment: I must say that picture looks quite old to me. Like from a 70s movie.

Comment: Speaking as a person of womb I find that image rather sexist. They could have shown someone wearing clothes...

Comment: "Black Lives Matter" is not a person, not even in the expansive legal sense in which, say, Citizens United is a legal person. Asking whether "Black Live Matter" did or said something is nonsensical.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found [this very very similar Facebook post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170531011752/https://www.facebook.com/blacklivesmatter1/posts/1669039406738983), from an account that is now deleted:

[image: “Products shown: BLM T-shirt” with picture given in question]

- Perhaps the most significant thing to note about this is that the account was @blacklivesmatter**1**, which CNN reported on in the article [The biggest Black Lives Matter page on Facebook is fake](https://qz.com/1248419/black-lives-matters-biggest-facebook-page-was-allegedly-run-by-a-white-australian-man/):

  > For at least a year, the biggest page on Facebook purporting to be part of the Black Lives Matter movement was a scam with ties to a middle-aged white man in Australia, a review of the page and associated accounts and websites conducted by CNN shows.

  Not to be confused with the [Black Lives Matter Global Network Foundation Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/BlackLivesMatter/) ("BlackLivesMatter"), which is even verified.
- The post I found is from May 14, 2017 at 9:16pm and it looks like the same account as the one above (and with the account deleted there's next to no chance of finding the other post). The image is also slightly different...
- [SanCopha League](http://sancophaleague.tumblr.com/post/80973354448/my-message-we-have-to-always-think-race-first-if) posted this image earlier on Tumblr. Mysteriously, both the image here and the one I found on Facebook have the attribution to SanCopha League in the corner while the image in the question doesn't (but instead looks like it has a suspicious patch of blackness there instead, as if someone sloppily tried to get rid of something in the corner the exact size and shape as the text in the other images.)